# Is it preferred to use a global pthread_mutex_t in C projects?

Tags: c, multithreading

How is `pthread_mutex_t` used for a multi source C project.

Is there a global `pthread_mutex_t` in a header file or does each source file defines it's own?
How many times `pthread_mutex_init` is used? only once per mutex?

So if we use a global mutex, we only need to use `pthread_mutex_init` once in the beginning of `main`?

Comment: IMO, a mutex variable should be declared somewhere close to the variables that it protects. Maybe as a member of the same `struct`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How is `pthread_mutex_t` used for a multi source C project.

It really depends on the project itself and what the code needs to do. There's no "standard" way of doing this.

> Is there a global `pthread_mutex_t` in a header file or does each source file define it's own?

Again, it depends on what is needed. There is no rule saying that there should only be one global mutex or that there should be one mutex per source file. It depends. If a resource needs to be managed by different files then a unique global mutex can be used. If another resource needs to be managed only by the code that is defined in a single source file then there's no need to make it available globally (and it can be defined `static`).

Yes, `pthread_mutex_init` should be used once per mutex.

> So if we use a global mutex, we only need to use `pthread_mutex_init` once in the beginning of `main`?

Yes. That would be one way to do it.

Another, perhaps better approach is to just initialize the variable at its definition:

```
pthread_mutex_t my_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
// or
static pthread_mutex_t my_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

This way there's no need to call `pthread_mutex_init` and you don't risk forgetting it.

Comment: I just wanted to confirm something, a mutex guarantees some code gets executed only by 1 thread at a time right? but it does not have control over `which thread` access it first. I.e there is no order guarantee in threads and no way of doing it?

Comment: @Josh yes, there is no guarantee about the order. If you want to guarantee order, you generally have to use thread signaling or semaphores. Also, "only 1 thread at a time" is of course true only as long as all the threads use the mutex correctly (lock/unlock).

Comment: @Josh: Used correctly, mutexes usually don't lock code but data. That is, they don't ensure that a particular piece of code is executing in only one thread at a time; they ensure that a particular piece of data is only being accessed by one thread at a time. The same code can be executing with different data just fine. But different code that accesses the same data is not fine.

Comment: a mutex locks instructions, not data.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should expect to use one mutex for each "unit" of shared state that's accessed by multiple threads. If one such unit is global state, then you would expect to have a global mutex alongside it, and it can be statically initialized with `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`. If it's a data structure that can exist in multiple instances in allocated storage, you normally want to place the mutex protecting it inside the data structure itself, and initialize it with `pthread_mutex_init` when it's created, before its existence is exposed to multiple threads.